# Is the local inverse of an analytical function locally analytical as well?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponentiation

Take for example $f(z)=e^z$, so the inverse is $z(f) = \ln(f) + n\pi i$ for an arbitrarily chosen (but fixed) branch $n\in\mathbb N$. Now if $f$ is restricted to e.g. $0<|1-f|<1$ such that the essential singularity at $f=0$ is not part of the definition region, is $z(f)$ then analytical in that region?

Comment: yes, you can write down (formally) the power series of the inverse and show it converges or you can write derivatives of $f^{-1}$ in terms of the derivatives of $f$.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem.

Comment: @yoyo: you mean yes for the example but in general I have to...

Comment: ...use the formula linked by @joriki and prove the convergence on a case-to-case basis?

Comment: The theorem I linked to says "$g$ is analytic at the point $b = f(a)$". That $g$ is analytic implies that its power series converges in some neighbourhood of $b$.

Comment: @joriki: oh, I missed that line, thanks! so the answer is simply yes, could you post that as an answer so this question doesn't remain unanswered (to the system I mean)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Lagrange inversion theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem): "$g$ is analytic at the point $b=f(a)$".